# probsoln: How to link problem with its solution?

Tags: hyperref, probsoln

I simplified the example on page 13 and 14 of the `probsoln` [package documentation](https://osl.ugr.es/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/probsoln/probsoln.pdf) to ask the following question: *How can I link the problems with its solutions?* (The solutions are already linked with the corresponding problems.)

**MWE (2 files!)**

derivatives.tex

```
\begin{defproblem}{cosxsqsinx}%
\begin{onlyproblem}%
$y = \cos(x^2)\sin x$.%
\end{onlyproblem}%
\begin{onlysolution}%
\[\frac{dy}{dx} = -\sin(x^2)2x\sin x + \cos(x^2)\cos x\]
\end{onlysolution}%
\end{defproblem}
```

main.tex

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{probsoln}
\usepackage[colorlinks,linkcolor=blue]{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\hideanswers

\chapter{Differentiation}
% randomly select 25 problems from derivatives.tex and add to
% the data set called 'deriv'
\loadrandomproblems[deriv]{1}{derivatives}
% Display the problems
\renewcommand{\theenumi}{\thechapter.\arabic{enumi}}
\begin{enumerate}
\foreachproblem[deriv]{\item\label{prob:\thisproblemlabel}\thisproblem}
\end{enumerate}
% You may need to change \theenumi back here

\appendix
\chapter{Solutions}
\showanswers
\begin{itemize}
\foreachdataset{\thisdataset}{%
\foreachproblem[\thisdataset]{\item[\ref{prob:\thisproblemlabel}]\thisproblem}
}
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

**Screenshot**

I want "1.1" on page 1 link to the solution...

[image]

...on page 2. Like the "1.1" on page 2 links to the exercise on page 1.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{probsoln}
\usepackage[colorlinks,linkcolor=blue]{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\hideanswers

\chapter{Differentiation}
% randomly select 25 problems from derivatives.tex and add to
% the data set called 'deriv'
\loadrandomproblems[deriv]{1}{derivatives}
% Display the problems
\renewcommand{\theenumi}{\thechapter.\arabic{enumi}}
\begin{enumerate}
\foreachproblem[deriv]{%
 \item[{\refstepcounter{enumi}\label{prob:\thisproblemlabel}%
        \hyperref[sol:\thisproblemlabel]{\theenumi}}]
       \thisproblem}
\end{enumerate}
% You may need to change \theenumi back here

\appendix
\chapter{Solutions}
\showanswers
\begin{itemize}
\foreachdataset{\thisdataset}{%
\foreachproblem[\thisdataset]{%
 \item[\ref{prob:\thisproblemlabel}\phantomsection\label{sol:\thisproblemlabel}]\thisproblem}
}
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```